# Move container registrations to a new assembly with Prism.Unity.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, unity-container

I'm currently using Prism with Unity in a Xamarin.Forms project.

I'm using

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) {}
```

to register my classes in App.xaml.cs, but as my project grows, so does this method / numbers of usings, etc.

I thought about offloading some of the registrations to their respective namespaces. That is, if I have a namespace for Users, I can have a class like this:

```
    public sealed class UsersRegistry : IRegistry {

        public UsersRegistry(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
        }
    }
```

I started by using assembly scanning to find all classes that implement IRegistry, but I'm coming up a little short on how to create the class and pass in the container used by Prism.

I was attempting something like this:

```
           var registries = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(type => typeof(IRegistry).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsInterface);

            foreach (var type in registries) {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, <get unity container here>);
            }
```

But I'm not certain this is the correct direction.

Also, it doesn't have to be this particular way. My main goal here is to break out the registrations for navigation and my various types into a more manageable system.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism provides this functionality in the form of [modules](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/551b4554da6d33f52c36124fbdb908e15477cf75/src/Prism.Core/Modularity/IModule.cs).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I guess my concern with modules is that it's specifically tied to Prism, and it'd require me to reference Prism in my business layer. In addition, not every UI that consumes my business layer uses Prism, so I wouldn't want to have to include it there. My hope was that if I could just pass the container used by Prism to my registration classes I could keep all of my registrations (for the most part) in the business layer for any app that is consuming those objects. Passing in the container would allow me to just use regular Unity syntax to register classes.

Comment: And maybe there's an argument to be made for not setting up registration this way. Maybe it could mean that a UI layer that consumes my business layer, but only uses a tiny fraction of it would have dozens of unused registrations, but I'm not sure if that's worth the trade off of having multiple registrations of the same classes for a bunch of different apps either.

Comment: I did realize that I can call Activator.CreateInstance(type, containerRegistry.GetContainer()); to pass an instance of the container to my IRegistry class. My class then had an instance of the container used by Prism. I don't know though. I'm rethinking some of this, and maybe it doesn't make sense to do this. There could be a chance that there's a React based UI created for some of this, and that wouldn't even have the opportunity to take advantage of these IRegistry classes. Maybe it is best to keep the registrations on the client even if there's repeats between the Web API and client?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Prism.Core in the Business Layer - e.g. `IEventAggregator` is really helpful if you need a small messaging service.

Comment: I suppose that's true. Thank you.